# How to search array of fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I have a index in elastic search called `professor`

- If for cross field i need "AND" condition
- for same field array i need to OR condition

1. I need to search `subject` which is `Physics` or `Accounting` this is array of fields(OR) statement
2. I need to search `type` is `Permanent`(&) condition
3. I need to search `Location` is `NY`(&) condition
4. There is chance that {'type':['Contract','Guest']} type also coming as list

```
test = [{'id':1,'name': 'A','subject': ['Maths','Accounting'],'type':'Contract', 'Location':'NY'},
      { 'id':2,'name': 'AB','subject': ['Physics','Engineering'],'type':'Permanent','Location':'NY'},
    {'id':3,'name': 'ABC','subject': ['Maths','Engineering'],'type':'Permanent','Location':'NY'}]
```

Query is below,3rd one got it, How to add `1 and 2`

```
content_search = es.search(index="professor", body={
    "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "Location.keyword": "NY"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
content_search ['hits']['hits']
```

Expected out is id `[{ 'id':2,'name': 'AB','subject': ['Physics','Engineering'],'type':'Permanent','Location':'NY'}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need to use the [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html), to wrap all your conditions

Adding a working example with index data(same as that in question), search query, and search result

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "type.keyword": "Permanent"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Location.keyword": "NY"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "subject.keyword": "Accounting"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "subject.keyword": "Physics"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64370980",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.8365774,
        "_source": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "AB",
          "subject": [
            "Physics",
            "Engineering"
          ],
          "type": "Permanent",
          "Location": "NY"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: can i use filter here

Comment: Yes @Nons you can use `filter` in place of `must`

Comment: filtering from match_all i am just filtering out. that is basic question, did i miss something

Comment: @Nons `filter` refers to that clause (query) must appear in matching documents. However, unlike `must` the score of the query will be ignored.

Comment: @Nons your expected output was document with `id` 2, that satisfies all your conditions?

Comment: I am just doing a match_all and thought of filtering out, that is my asking. just a doubt

Comment: If you want to just extract those document, that has `location=NY`, you can use this search query: 
`{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "Location.keyword": "NY"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: @Nons you can use `filter` in place of `must` to filter out the result(which you want to retrieve) from all the result :) Just remember that scoring is ignored in filter

Comment: yes but i need to extract subject.keyword": "Accounting", "Physics" also

Comment: How to improvise to write DSL query i m new to this?

Comment: @Nons you can use `filter` in place of `must` only. But in your case, you want to extract `subject.keyword": "Accounting" OR "Physics`, then this is an OR condition, so you have to use `should` clause for that. `should` can be termed as **logical OR** and must can be termed as **logical AND** operator

Comment: one last query, by default there is no filter values, if i did not get any filter values then i have to pass  "query":{ "match_all":{}}}. can i take care of the condition with above query

Comment: I have added one question for better understanding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64372692/how-to-search-on-multiple-fields-of-array-in-elasticsearch

Comment: @Nons please go through my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64372969/10348758 to your new question and let me know if your issue is resolved?