# How to search on multiple fields of array in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I have a index in elastic search called `professor`

- If for cross field i need "AND" condition
- for same field array i need to OR condition

1. I need to search `subject` which is `Physics` or `Accounting` this is array of fields(OR) statement

   AND
2. I need to search `type` is `Permanent` or `GUEST` condition this is array of fields(OR) statement

   AND
3. I need to search `Location` is `NY`(&) condition

```
test = [{'id':1,'name': 'A','subject': ['Maths','Accounting'],'type':'Contract', 'Location':'NY'},
      { 'id':2,'name': 'AB','subject': ['Physics','Engineering'],'type':'Permanent','Location':'NY'},
    {'id':3,'name': 'ABC','subject': ['Maths','Engineering'],'type':'Permanent','Location':'NY'},
{'id':4,'name':'ABCD','subject': ['Physics','Engineering'],'type':['Contract','Guest'],'Location':'NY'}]
```

Query is below,3rd one got it, How to add `1 and 2`

```
content_search = es.search(index="professor", body={
    "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "Location.keyword": "NY"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
content_search ['hits']['hits']
```

Expected out is id `[{ 'id':2,'name': 'AB','subject': ['Physics','Engineering'],'type':'Permanent','Location':'NY'},{'id':4,'name':'ABCD','subject': ['Physics','Engineering'],'type':['Contract','Guest'],'Location':'NY'}]`

Comment: do you want to have a search query that satisfies all your condition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The filter clause (query) must appear in matching documents. However
> unlike must the score of the query will be ignored. Filter clauses are
> executed in filter context, meaning that scoring is ignored and
> clauses are considered for caching.

Please go through this Elasticsearch documentation on [bool queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html), to get a detailed understanding about it.

Adding a working example with index data(same as that in question), search query, and search result

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "Location.keyword": "NY"
        }
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "subject.keyword": "Accounting"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "subject.keyword": "Physics"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                   "type.keyword": "Permanent"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "type.keyword": "Guest"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64370980",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.10536051,
        "_source": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "AB",
          "subject": [
            "Physics",
            "Engineering"
          ],
          "type": "Permanent",
          "Location": "NY"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64370980",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 0.10536051,
        "_source": {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "ABCD",
          "subject": [
            "Physics",
            "Engineering"
          ],
          "type": [
            "Contract",
            "Guest"
          ],
          "Location": "NY"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Another Search Query:**

> You can even use [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) that returns documents that contain
> one or more exact terms in a provided field.The terms query is the
> same as the term query, except you can search for multiple values.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "subject.keyword": [
              "Physics",
              "Accounting"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "type.keyword": [
              "Guest",
              "Permanent"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Location.keyword": "NY"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "subject.keyword": [
              "Physics",
              "Accounting"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "type.keyword": [
              "Guest",
              "Permanent"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Location.keyword": "NY"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "ABCD"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `"query": {"bool": {"must": {"query_string": { "query": 'ABCD'}}}}`  How to add a search string `ABCD` in above query?

Comment: In entire values how to search the 'ABCD' string

Comment: @Nons please go through my updated answer, I have added the search query there. And let me know if this resolved your issue ?